# The page loads twice in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm having trouble writing vue. I am using vue and vuetify.

There are `A` and`B` pages. There is no problem with entering the `A` or`B` page only once.

However, when the page is entered as below, the created function of `A` is called twice.

`A` -> `B` -> `A`

**menuselector.vue**

```
<template>
   <v-list>
      <template v-for='(eachmenu) in menu'>
         <v-list-item
            :to='eachmenu.path'
         >
            <v-list-item-title>
              {{eachmenu.title}}
            </v-list-item-title>
         </v-list-item>
      </template>
   </v-list>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   name: 'selector',
   data() {
      return {
         menu: [
            {
               title: 'A',
               path: '/A',
            }
            {
               title: 'B',
               path: '/B',
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

**router.vue**

```
export default new Router({
   mode: 'history',
   base: process.env.BASE_URL,
   routes: [
      {
         path: '/',
         redirect: '/A',
         component: TestComponent,
         children: [
            {
               path: 'A',
               component: () => import('@/component/A.vue'),
               name: 'Acomponent',
            },
            {
               path: 'B',
               component: () => import('@/component/B.vue'),
               name: 'Bcomponent',
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
})
```

**A.vue&B.vue**

```
<template>
   test
</template>

<script>
export default {
   beforeCreate() {
      console.log('beforeCreate');
   }
   created() {
      console.log('created');
   }
}
</script>
```

Console output is below.

[image]

what was problem???

Comment: Does route **/B** load its **created()** twice? You have a **redirect: '/A',** in your code, before the nested routes - that may cause problems,

Comment: why wouldn't it load twice, the component is rendered twice since you left the page.

Comment: @muka.gergely What problem are you talking about? If I go to www.domain.com, I try to load the page by redirecting to www.domain.com/A. 
Is this a problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think "loading" is correct word here. Code needed for component is loaded from server only once as you can check in Dev Tools Network tab
2. When switching routes, component for old route is destroyed and component for new route is created. Its default behavior of Vue dynamic component (it is what `<router-view>` uses for switching components). You can change that by using [`<keep-alive>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components). Be sure to check documentation and understand implications - your app will use more memory

```html
  <keep-alive>
    <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
  </keep-alive>
```

Comment: sorry, This did not solve it. You said a new route was created in 2, when is it made? When I go to the `A` menu, create on` A` is called. After that, when I go to the `B` menu, create on` B` is called. When I go back to the `A` menu,` `A`'s created function is called twice. The problem is, if an old route is destroyed and a new route is created, shouldn't it be created when I leave the `A` menu?